# cpan fails with "Error code 130, while making 'pm_to_blib'"

Tags: windows-7, perl, cpan

I recently installed Perl on my Windows 7 machine.

Upon running `cpan App::cpanminus`, I got the following error:

```
D:\Perl>cpan App::cpanminus
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.199)
Database was generated on Mon, 04 Feb 2013 07:21:27 GMT
Running install for module 'App::cpanminus'
Running make for M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.5021.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.61)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.034)
Checksum for D:\Strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MI\MIYAGAWA\App-cpanminus-1
.5021.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.76)
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4401)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.110930)
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.73)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.5021.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for App::cpanminus
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequ
isites
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.49)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Cannot copy 'lib/App/cpanminus.pm' to 'blib\lib\App\cpanminus.pm': No suc
h file or directory
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1
dmake.EXE:  Error code 130, while making 'pm_to_blib'
  MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.5021.tar.gz
  D:\Strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that i set an autorun in my cmd using regedit HKEY->Software->Microsoft->Command processor->autorun to change to my working directory.

This makes the dmake program look in the wrong place. After deleting autorun everything worked like a charm.